# Stop cakephp 3.x FORM to multi-submit after multi-click on SUBMIT Button

Tags: php, forms, cakephp-3.x

I'm working with cakephp 3.x there are many ways to submit a form for actions such as add, edit etc. I've facing the issue of users multi-submitting a single form by clicking multiple times on the button.

Does cakephp 3.x provide the facility to stop a form being submitted more than once, at any time?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to redirect page after completion of form submission. This will resolve the problem.

Use `$this->redirect()` Function for this purpose.

You can find more on this here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

in "***Flow Control***" Section

Comment: Actually My query is; after the click and before the completion of the form submit request. At that time we can click on the cakephp form button multi-time. If we click on the button on multi-time then multi records are added on the database.

Comment: @PankajSharma then you can use JavaScript to disable the button after clicking the button once. Hope this will help.

Comment: we cannot use click event. Because if suppose any frontend validation is using on the form then it will disable the button and will need to refresh page again. so I found one better solution to disable the button on form submit only via     $( "form" ).submit(function() {
  return this.some_flag_variable;
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "form" ).submit(function() {
  $("button id will come here").attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

1. NOTE:- button id will be your submit button id